# What does this code in waitForKeyElements do?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm using [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) in Greasemonkey and don't understand this snippet:

```
if (!alreadyFound) {
                //--- Call the payload function.
                var cancelFound     = actionFunction (jThis);
                if (cancelFound)
                    btargetsFound   = false;
                else
                    jThis.data ('alreadyFound', true);
            }
```

`actionFunction` is my callback I pass in. It should only return `undefined` unless I code it to return something, right? Under what conditions would I do that? `btargetsFound` needs to be True to stop waitForKeyElements from calling itself later. So returning something somehow means "one of the elements I found, even though I found it and called the payload function on it, I still need to retry?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Another way to say it would be the callback can return `true` to say "This element matches the selector, but isn't the one that I want, try again later". I'm guessing that is for cases where what you want is built in several stages by multiple AJAX calls, or something along those lines.

Note that returning `true` will cause the callback to be called again with the same element the next time the timer fires.